# psacct просмотр статистики за предыдущие дни

Tags: debian, логирование, мониторинг

Здравствуйте прошу помощи

перерыл кучу информации по пакету psacct, но нигде не пишут как посмотреть историю, везде одна и таже инфа

я конечно предполагаю что может руки кривые на предмет гугления но прошу сильно не пинать если че не так

в общем вопрос такой

Debian установлен пакет psacct

собираю стату sa --user-summary

лог пишется в /var/log/account

в логах вижу pacct , pacct.0 и остальное уже в gz

правильно ли я понимаю что команда sa --user-summary выводит стату из файла pacct в логах за текущий день

и если да то

1) как посмотреть историю, допустим за вчера, по пользователю, та что по идее должна лежать в gz

по датам вижу что лог записывается в 2.14 - это время максимального сбора инфы за сутки

как выяснить нагрузку скажем за вчера

по идее надо распаковать gz архивчик за вчера, но как заставить sa считать из него инфу и засветить ну и конечно важно не смешивать данные со статой за сегодня

спасибо